# iPad storyboard app - popover and modal delegates

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, protocols, uipopovercontroller

I'm pretty new to iOS development and I'm coding my first iPad App.

I have 3 questions:

1) I noticed that there is a **UIPopoverControllerDelegate** Protocol for delegates of Popovers. However, I couldn't find any for Modals. I need to know why there is no official delegate for Modals?

2) Is it correct in general to declare a custom protocol for such cases? What is the correct approach?

3) I was looking for a complete example of Modals and Popovers (with **UITableViewController** inside) for iPad where Storyboard is used but unfortunately, all I could find are outdated examples. I have a feeling that Storyboard is sort of not recommended for iPad apps. Is it correct?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. The popover controller's delegate deals with the dismissal of the popover, which can happen when the user taps anywhere else on the screen. For other presented view controllers, this is not the case, dismissal can only be achieved by code you have written, so there is no need for a delegate.
2. Declare a delegate protocol if you need one, yes. That is the correct approach. There are dozens of examples around.
3. Storyboards are recommended by Apple for all iOS projects. For iPad projects, you need a damn big monitor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
1) What if I have a UITableViewController in Popover and I want to pass the data back to the delegate? I'm asking this, because I suppose that UIPopoverControllerDelegate could probably have a @required function for this, but it doesn't! And it makes me think that maybe, I should not use it? or I'm doing something wrong?

3) I noticed there is a segue type "Popover" in the storyboard. Which one is better? to use the Segue directly from the button or do in the ViewController code?

Comment: If you want to pass data back then you need to declare a custom delegate, and it will be you table view controller's delegate, not the popover's. There is no "better" way of doing it, it depends on the rest of the project, what you are comfortable with etc. If everything else is in the storyboard, do the popover in there as well.